# VS: Dependency content files not picked up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, installation

I have an Setup project that installs App.exe.

App.exe depends on
1) A third party library NLog.dll which comes with NLog.xml.
2) another project in the solution which has content files Lib.xml.

To the setup project, I added "Primary output from App" and "Content Files from App".  The installer didn't pick up the third party lib config (NLog.xml) and the content files of its dependency (Lib.xml).  How do I instruct VS to pick up those two?

Note that all these files are available in App/bin/Release/.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that files are really necesary for the project?? or they are just the helpers file (that contains the help of the class).. Did you inspect them?

Comment: yes, they are necessary.  At least Lib.xml is definitely required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since config files are .config and your dll are using XML, VS assume that those files are the help files for the class..
You should add the files manually to the setup project. VS will not add them.

Comment: would it help if I set the files as Resource?  They are really plain resource files that the app needs.

Comment: I think so... did you try it?

Comment: no even setting the files to resources couldn't get VS to pick them up.  It is going to be a nightmare down the road.